# Is there evidence that English speakers associate black with bad and/or white with good

Tags: english, semantics, reference-request

Prompted by the recent move towards replacing the terms "blacklist" and "whitelist", I wonder if there is research around the topic of how people feel about the words "black" and "white", whether the feeling is positive, negative or neutral.

The types of research could be anything. Something like tallying phrase use frequency against how negative or positive the phrase is perceived and if the phrase contains the word "black" or "white", or perhaps reaction time studies presenting the word "white" or "black" in a positive context vs a negative one.

Hopefully that gives an impression of what I'm looking for.

I'm not sure what to search for, so any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Try this on [elu.se]

Comment: We don't service reference requests on EL&U

Comment: But this is still specific on English, unfortunately.

Comment: So what is the [tag:english] tag for?

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica I want to bring this up on the EL&U meta to see if I can get support for English-only questions that would otherwise be a good fit for here. I can't see a meta post outlawing mono-language questions, could you link me to it, please?

Comment: Well, I don't have a meta pointer ready, but there is a ready-formulated reason for close votes here: "Language-specific grammar and usage questions are off-topic unless primarily concerned with linguistics rather than usage. There are many language-specific sites where such questions are welcomed; see: http://stackexchange.com/sites"

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica: this is a question about research on word meanings/emotional valences (a linguistic topic), not a question about “usage” itself. That is, it’s not just “how are black/white used” but “what evidence do linguists use to determine how black/white are used”

Comment: [Does a master's thesis on 'authentic' count](https://ny.eater.com/2019/1/18/18183973/authenticity-yelp-reviews-white-supremacy-trap)?

Comment: @Mitch very interesting. That sort of thing, but including analysis about "black" or "white" (unless I missed something in the article?).

Comment: @MattEllen I'd support that proposal on EL&U.  I'd actually enjoy more technical and linguistic questions on our site; as you know, we are mostly awash with work-a-day drivel.

Comment: Just for a lead, this paper and its references seem to address the question: https://doi.org/10.2466/pms.1966.22.3.771

Comment: @JeremyNeedle oh! thanks.

Comment: Don't you think we've had enough of this kind of stuff"? I believe that most people have.

Comment: @BillJ I haven't had enough time to read the references in Jeremy's link, so clearly I haven't had enough research into how people feel about words. I take it you have?

Comment: Check this empirical study: https://www.thecollegefix.com/study-black-coached-ncaa-football-teams-penalized-more-than-those-led-by-whites/

Comment: @Davius while that is a worrying trend in sports, I'm not sure how it relates to the language. It's not about the use of the word black, but about the colour of coach's skin.